# Unable to clone from bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am able to open bitbucket.or from the IE/browser. But I can not clone the repository from the command-line. It is getting time-out.

fatal: unable to access 'https://XXXXXX@bitbucket.org/XXXXXX/XXX.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Timed out

Please can you suggest anything.

TIA!!!

Comment: Bitbucket can occasionally go down, so you should check on this first.  Beyond this, check your local connection.  Can you access _any_ HTTPS website?

Comment: we have proxy setup. Using this I can connect to bitbucket.org and browse through different streams. But whenever I try to clone the repo it gives the 443 time out error.

Comment: Its due to your proxy settings, you are blocked on port 443 by your organization

Answer (score 1):

If you are using proxy set up the proxy setting for your git CLI

```
# set the proxy configuration for git
git config --global http.proxy https://user......
```

If this doesn't work you can switch off the ssl verify as well

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

In your case i don't think ssl verify is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your valuable comments. I was able to solve this by adding the following section to my gitcongif (C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc) file

[http]

```
proxy = http://proxy.at.your.org:8080
```

Hope this helps others as well!!